# Plugin init hook

Tags: hooks

Is there a plugin init hook that runs whenever the plugin is being loaded? I'd like to link the functions for requiring files and defining constants to such a hook if it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the [`plugins_loaded`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-settings.php#L208) hook for normal Plugins and [`muplugins_loaded`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-settings.php#L170), which runs earlier.

My best advice for hooks is making cross file searches for `do_action` or dump the content of the `all` hook with `$GLOBALS['wp_filter'][ current_filter() ];`.